# IBM MQ JAR 9.2.1 connection issue from Spring Boot 2.3.5

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq

Does anyone experience any IBM MQ JAR version 9.2.1 (or above) connection issue from Spring Boot 2.3.5?
We encounter this message: MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR. We do not have this issue when connecting from POJO.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace.  Please edit and add to your question not in a comment.

Comment: Please also provide details of the java jdk / jre that you are using, along with steps that you are using to set up TLS in your Spring Boot app.